# How can one count iterations of Angular 9 ngFor without using index or .length?

Tags: angular, angular9

I have an Angular loop that has a conditional check in it. Thus, the usual answer of using the .length on the array, or using the i from index won't tell me how many items are *showing*.

```
<form [formGroup]="paymentsForm">
<div formArrayName="arrVoucherLines">  
    <div *ngFor="let line of paymentsForm.get('arrVoucherLines')['controls']; index as i"
     [formGroupName]="i">

     <div *ngIf="dateCheckingConditionalFunctionPlaceholder()">

         <mat-checkbox formControlName='FlagPayInvoice'></mat-checkbox>
         Issued: {{line.value.DateTimeLocalInvoiceIssued |date:'MM/dd'}}
         Due: {{line.value.DateTimeLocalInvoiceDue |date:'MM/dd'}}
        ... variety of other voucer info
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Displaying the total amount of items is easy, but I want to also be able to display how many are shown and how many were skipped. If I could have a "variable++" in the loop that would be pretty easy.

Desired result would be to end up with something that I could:

```
Total invoices {{blah.length}}
Invoices Shown {{count}}
Invoices not yet due: {{blah.length-count}}
```

The usage case is the user is selecting a cutoff date on the form, and only showing the bills due before that date.

Comment: can you filter your array in the component instead of using the *ngIf in the template?

Comment: All things are possible: I could pre-filter (and re-filter upon selection of new date). I do remain curious if counting variables in loops are even possible.

Comment: provide data to the view. don't let the view do the heavy lifting. So that means pre-cook the data you'd like displayed in a function (or component method if you like to express it like that)

Comment: Didn't test it, but couldn't you use `*ngIf="dateCheckingConditionalFunctionPlaceholder() && ++counter"`? If the left side of an `&&` expression returns falsy, the right side is never read. Mind the `++counter` instead of `counter++` if your counter starts at 0, since 0 is falsy.

Comment: Not very useful, but you could count how many children have been generated by the `*ngIf`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6s14e. However, this requires to declare a `@ViewChildren` variable in the component. The best way is to do your calculations in the component or in a filter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could write a simple directive that do the job. Check [this repro on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8qyrwd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). It counts only 2 divs out of 12 because the directive is triggered only if the div is created. Here is the code just in case stackblitz does not works:

app.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  array = new Array(12);
  counter = 0;

  addCounter(e:number) {
    this.counter += 1;
  } 
}
```

app.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="i === 3 || i ===4" ngInit (trigger)="addCounter()">
        item {{i}}
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div>Total items = {{array.length}}</div>
<div>Generated items = {{counter}}</div>
<div>Skipped items = {{array.length - counter}}</div>
```

ng-init.directive.ts:

```
import {Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngInit]'
})
export class NgInitDirective {
  @Output() trigger: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.trigger.emit();
  }
}
```

In the html file I used the index to add a condition on the displayed div, you have a condition based on something else but it does not change anything.
For the number of items skipped, well `array.length - this.counter` will do the job.

Comment: Provided solution is 1) simple 2) provided in a workable stackblitz 3) copied here as per stackoverflow recommendations not to link to answers and perhaps most importantly 4) directly and completely answers the question without "have you tried?" questions.  Happy to award the points, and I learned something new! 

Comment: Haha well thanks, glad i could help :) Two days ago i used it at work to solve a console error "Expression has changed after it was checked". I had to do something AFTER a div was loaded (to get its size) and it worked as well, so it can be veeery useful in this way as well (prevent you from using afterViewInit + changeDetection, maybe there is other solution but idk).